# PHP Wrong Date AD

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to get the `'passwordLastSet'` attribute from Active Directory, but it returns with 1 hour less.

Return: `11-05-2018 10:30:07`

Should be: `11-05-2018 11:30:07` (real last time password changed)

[image]

Active Directory server (Windows Server 2012) is at the same time of the PHP server (my computer for development)

My time zone on PHP is set to Europe/Lisbon, the date function returns the correct time.

I'm using `LDAP tools`

My query:

```
    $user = $ldap->buildLdapQuery()
        ->select(['username', 'emailAddress', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'passwordLastSet'])
        ->fromUsers()
        ->where(['username' => $username])
        ->getLdapQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
```

Return:

```
date_format($user->passwordLastSet, 'd-m-Y H:i:s')
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: It's returning the correct time for the specified timezone; your current timezone is GMT+1 (Summer Time) - you're skipping the timezone in your: `date_format()` call.

Comment: @CD001 I've defined this on my config file: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");

This should work on the whole site, right?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($user->passwordLastSet)` ? Would be helpful to know what you're *actually* getting from Active Directory.

Comment: @CD001 getting this:

`object(DateTime)#52 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-05-11 10:30:07.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" }`

Comment: Right - the timezone you're getting from Active Directory is `GMT` but `date_format` doesn't know that, to see what I mean, try: `$arDate = new DateTime('2018-05-11 10:30:07', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
$arDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo $arDate->format('r');`

Comment: @CD001 Thanks, it's working now, but this way will it work even when the time change back to +0000?

Comment: Should do - you're always holding the same *time* you just have to pass in the timezone specific to where you're using it; so if you need to update Active Directory, set the timezone back to UTC first.

Answer (score 0):

you can below example:

```
 $data= "2010-03-21";
 $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($user->passwordLastSet)` gives:

```
object(DateTime)#52 (3) {
    ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-05-11 10:30:07.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(1)
    ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

This tells us that `$user->passwordLastSet` is a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object holding a timezone of `UTC` so when you're formatting it, it's merely outputting that value - and since you're currently on daylight savings time (`UTC+1`) it's an hour behind.

You need to change the timezone on that `DateTime` object before outputting it, like so:

```
$user->passwordLastSet->setTimeZone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo $user->passwordLastSet->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```